# Sculpting a gold mine off Google Maps

Tags: sculpt

if I’ve grabbed this 3d data off Google Maps but it hasn’t captured the detail of how deep the mine is; is there a way to do that without affecting the texture map too much?

[image]

ie this is how deep it is really…

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe try the [BlenderGIS addon](https://github.com/domlysz/BlenderGIS) to get the true height information and geographic data?

Comment: Yeah that's what I used and this was the result I got, which unfortunately isn't accurate.